# sort recommit ignore python file even if asked to scan specifically

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, isort

I have:

```
  - repo: https://github.com/asottile/seed-isort-config
    rev: v2.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: seed-isort-config
  - repo: https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort
    rev: 5.9.2
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        name: Run isort to sort imports
        types: [python3]
```

I execute:

```
pre-commit run --files myproject/draft.py
```

What I see in the logs:

```
seed isort known_third_party.............................................Passed
Run isort to sort imports............................(no files to check)Skipped
```

I don't understand why it says skip? I gave it direct path to python file how can there be no files to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have set `types: [python3]` which only matches extensionless scripts specifically with a `#!/usr/bin/env python3` shebang

since your `myproject/draft.py` file does not match that there are no appropriate files to run for `isort` and so it is skipped

remove that line, the default matches python files so you don't need to think about it

also, you don't need `seed-isort-config` as of `isort>=5` so you can remove that as well

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit, and seed-isort-config